# Sphinx autodoc django not working

Tags: python, django, python-sphinx

I've started using Sphinx for a django project, and I've hit a brick wall:

The modules are documented with something like this:

```
:mod:`models` Module
--------------------

.. automodule:: userprofile.models
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

The relevant code looks like this:

```
# models is django.db.models
class ProfileQuerystring(models.Model):
   [..]
```

The problem is that `ProfileQuerystring` does *not* appear in the HTML build. If, however, I remove the inheritance to `models.Model` (so the line looks like `class ProfileQuerystring:`) and re-build, the class gets documented.

This doesn't happen a few lines above that code, where I inherit from `models.Manager`.

*Can anyone help me out or at least give me a hint?*

**LATER EDIT**:

If I manually add it, it works:

```
.. automodule:: cinely.userprofile.models
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:

.. autoclass:: cinely.userprofile.models.ProfileQuerystring # <-- note this
```

So the class *can* be documented, but somehow `automodule` doesn't want to.

**LATER EDIT 2**:

I've tried removing the `__metaclass__` attribute from `Model`, but nothing happens. Also, since I've started editing the Django source, I took the chance to print something to the console, but nothing happened. I can confirm that the customized django is used, because I've uninstalled the `pip` installed one.

Comment: Good question (+1)... I don't have an answer, something that I would try to play around with, are the [autodoc defaults](http://sphinx.pocoo.org/ext/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_default_flags). They might be not the problem, but off the top of my head, those are the first thing that comes to my mind... :(

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5319484/146792) is of any help, thought to post the link at least.

Comment: @mac thanks for your help, but unfortunately I couldn't fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a tentative answer, and it might be wrong. It was simply too long to be put as a comment... However, if you take a look at the django source you will notice that `Model` and `Manager` have a different inheritance three. In particular, the *Model class* uses the `__metaclass__` attribute:

[Manager](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/manager.py#L45):

```
class Manager(object):
    # Tracks each time a Manager instance is created. Used to retain order.
    creation_counter = 0
```

[Model](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/base.py#L275):

```
class Model(object):
    __metaclass__ = ModelBase
    _deferred = False
```

My guess (but it's nothing more than that: a guess) is that when `ModelBase` creates the class, it manipulate the `__module__` attribute in a way that confuses sphinx and makes impossible for it to understand that the class is part of the module `models`.

```
module = attrs.pop('__module__')
new_class = super_new(cls, name, bases, {'__module__': module})
```

This hypothesis is consistent with your observation that - when the class to document is specified explicitly - sphinx has no problem in generating the documentation.

Does it help?

---

**EDIT:** Just occurred to me that a simple way to verify this hypothesis would be to temporary comment out the `__metaclass__` line in the `Model` class definition and see if this way sphinx picks it up...

Comment: thank you for your help; unfortunately it doesn't work (see my edit)

Comment: @GabiPurcaru - Can you post (or link to) a [ssccee](http://sscce.org/) we could experiment with? It's a fascinating puzzle to try to solve! :)

Comment: I'm very sorry for not answering this sooner; I've tried but couldn't isolate the problem (when I tried it on a clean django project it worked). That being given, I'm going to accept your answer because of your effort on helping me out. Thanks!